# How to access history of podcasts I have listened to in iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts.app

I don't know if this is possible or not: I would like to see the history of all the podcasts I have ever listened to. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 options: on the listen now page scroll to bottom and click recently played to view the previous podcasts listened to, even if you have not finished episodes, of every show.

Or to view specific show episodes go to the show itself and scroll down to the end and view the previous played episodes.

Unfortunately it doesn’t show the day or times listened to episodes but if you know you listened to them when they came out originally then it isn’t an issue.

Comment: Trying it right now (thanks for this answer!), going in from `Listen Now > Recently Played > See All`, it does say the date played, right under the "Play Again" button.  Yay progress! :-)  (I haven't tried the other path yet.  iOS 16.3 here.)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the phone logs this information. I have been wondering the same for as long as the Podcasts app came out in the App Store.

Unfortunately I have failed to find a way to extract data around the play history of my podcasts. I think this is impossible at this time.

Comment: it is now possible. this answer may have been correct in 2014. it's misleading today.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you are looking for, but from in show page you can scroll down to the end and tap “Previously Played” which will show you all the episodes you have listened to for the show.

[image]

Ideally you should be able to see any listened episode for all shows in one place, but this is the best thing I’ve found so far.

Answer (score -2):

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrRGi. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201859

Scroll down to the bottom of the Listen Now page of the ap. There is a recently played list. It will show back for quite always, not sure how long. [image]

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380125/237 - also can you please format your answer